# Google Play Games for Unity logging in user returns "GetToken failed with status code: NeedPermission"

Tags: android, authentication, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using the Google Services plugin for Unity, found here: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

I'm trying to add Google based authentication and get a server auth code.

Initializing the plugin like so:

```
PlayGamesClientConfiguration playGamesConfiguration = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .RequestServerAuthCode(false)
            .AddOauthScope("profile")
            .AddOauthScope("email")
            .Build();
PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(playGamesConfiguration);
PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = Debug.isDebugBuild;
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

And then to login the user, calling:

```
UnityEngine.Social.localUser.Authenticate((success, errorString) => {
// Code here
}
```

When I run the game, I see the "Connecting to Google Play Games" window pop up, but that should be followed by logging in the user and seeing the banner at the top of the screen.  But I get no banner.  Here are some relevant logs:

```
2295  2295 D GamesUnitySDK: Performing Android initialization of the GPG SDK
2295  2295 I Unity   : Building GPG services, implicitly attempts silent auth
2295  2694 I GamesNativeSDK: Auth operation started: SIGN IN
2295  2694 I GamesNativeSDK: Connecting to Google Play...
2295  2295 V GamesNativeSDK: Received Activity Resume Event.
1441  1452 W Auth    : [GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: NeedPermission
1383 17763 W Auth    : [GoogleAuthUtil] GoogleAuthUtil
2295  2295 V GamesNativeSDK: Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
2295  2694 I GamesNativeSDK: UI interaction required to connect to Google Play.
2295  2322 I Unity   : Success: False string: Authentication failed
```

The "GetToken failed with status code: NeedPermission" line seems to be the most important.  I assume GetToken is being called by the plugin internally to satisfy my request, but I don't know what permission it needs, or if the user is supposed to provide this or if this is a developer permission in the dashboard.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you gone through [this closed issue](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/10) from the same Github link?

Comment: I hadn't seen that issue.  From JohnTube's post showing the code comments, it sounds like NeedPermission is expected when a code is requested and then the user is supposed to see a dialog where they can provide that confirmation.  So maybe this is a bug in the plugin where it's not showing that popup.  Though this seems like a strange oversight from a plugin that's been around this long.

Comment: As a followup it turned out the Google Play Games console settings were incorrect.  There were a few issues there and I think the most important was that test users hadn't been given API access.  Since I didn't have access to the console, I wasn't able to verify the settings myself.

As an extra comment to Google, the more information provided in error codes, the easier it is to figure out what is misconfigured.  A lot of projects use distributed teams and being able to tell the other party EXACTLY what is misconfigured saves a LOT of debugging iteration time.

Comment: I think you should put in an answer (with more details if still possible). It'll be easier to see by other users who might encounter the same issue. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a followup it turned out the Google Play Games console settings were incorrect. There were a few issues there and I think the most important was that test users hadn't been given API access. Since I didn't have access to the console, I wasn't able to verify the settings myself.

As an extra comment to Google, the more information provided in error codes, the easier it is to figure out what is misconfigured. A lot of projects use distributed teams and person who can actually interact with the dev console may be more of a producer, and less of a technical person.  Being able to tell them EXACTLY what to do to fix the error message save a lot of debugging time.